# "A" and "an" with interjections

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, parentheses, sandhi

Basically I know how "a" and "an" are used:

> a member
> an adult member

but how is the same handled when the middle word is inserted parenthetically or even in brackets:

> I met a member of the club.
> I met **a/an** - adult - member of the club.
> I met **a/an** (adult) member of the club.

Should there be "a" used, because the main phrase is "a member" or should "an" be used because the adjective starts with a vowel? And is there a rule to quote?

Comment: The rule is that this is a rule of pronunciation, outranking even rules of grammar and punctuation.  I met a – shall we say adult – member of the club. // I met an – adult – member of the club. // I met an ... adult ... member of the club. // I met an (adult) member of the club. //  I met an 'adult ' member of the club. // I met a _quote_ adult _unquote_ member of the club.

Comment: Don't be distracted by the orthography - it's purely a matter of the ***sound***. And since ***adult*** starts with a "vowel sound", it's *always* preceded by ***an*** rather than ***a***, regardless of any punctuation marks that may occur in the written form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thank you for the explanation. I haven't found the linked thread mentioned in the reason for this being closed but now have read it and the explanation there was identical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: thanks for the explanation too